# Change content-type in S3 bucket policy for a specific file extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently when I place a property list file (plist extension) to a S3 bucket, it sets the Content-type to application/octet-stream for some reason. It causes issues when I download it in Objective-C (iOS).

How can change the bucket policy so it **automatically** sets the Content-type to text/plain

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot. The default content-type is "application/octet-stream".

Please find below the aws documentation for the same
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

The only option you have is setting the content-type at the time of upload or updating it once the upload is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Content-Type using the metadata properties of the file in S3 : [image]

Answer (score -3):

If you're on windows, and use CloudBerry, you can have a rule to set the Content-type for plist extension's automatically.  I use this for iOS files and it works great.  I dont have to remember to set it each time.

Greg