# Amazon S3 bucket policy to set "Content Type" to "application/pdf" for a specific folder in a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to set a bucket policy to override the default `octet-stream` `Content-Type` to `application/pdf` for a specific folder in a bucket, How can i write the bucket policy?

I'm not able to find any examples online and the `policygen` from `AWS` is confusing.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427041/change-content-type-in-s3-bucket-policy-for-a-specific-file-extension) post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do can be achieved through setting in the upload phase

I don't think it can be done with a bucket policy

Comment: While uploading i am setting but it still shows `application/octet-stream` in `S3`

Comment: Sorted it by changing the order of how its set.

Comment: @Nithin can you clarify how you did it in the end please?